# How to change the stdout and stderr log location of processes started by supervisor?

Tags: gunicorn, supervisord

So in my system, the supervisor captures stderr and stdout into these files:

```
root@3a1a895598f8:/var/log/supervisor# ls -l
total 24
-rw------- 1 root root 18136 Sep 14 03:35 gunicorn-stderr---supervisor-VVVsL1.log
-rw------- 1 root root     0 Sep 14 03:35 gunicorn-stdout---supervisor-lllimW.log
-rw------- 1 root root     0 Sep 14 03:35 nginx-stderr---supervisor-HNIPIA.log
-rw------- 1 root root     0 Sep 14 03:35 nginx-stdout---supervisor-2jDN7t.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1256 Sep 14 03:35 supervisord.log
```

But I would like to  change gunicorn's stdout and stderr log files 'location to /var/log/gunicorn and  fixed the file names for monitoring purpose.

This is what I have done in the config file:

```
[program:gunicorn]
stdout_capture_maxbytes=50MB
stderr_capture_maxbytes=50MB
stdout = /var/log/gunicorn/gunicorn-stdout.log
stderr = /var/log/gunicorn/gunicorn-stderr.log
command=/usr/bin/gunicorn -w 2 server:app
```

However it does not take any effect at all. Did I miss anything in the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Change `stdout` and `stderr` to `stdout_logfile` and `stderr_logfile` and this should solve your issue.

You can also change `childlogdir` in the main configuration to make all the child logs appear in another directory. If your are using Auto log mode the logfile names will be auto generated into the childlogdir specified without you needing to set `stdout_logfile`.

In order for your changes to be reflected you need to either restart the supervisor service with:

`service supervisord restart`

or

reload the config `supervisorctl reload` and update the config in the running processes `supervisorctl update`.

Documentation on this can be found here http://supervisord.org/logging.html#child-process-logs